# nexus 5 camera display

Tags: camera, nexus-5

How can I change the view on my camera so that the image I'm looking at is fully displayed on the screen? At the moment there is grey padding at the bottom with the camera icon I press to take a photo.

Comment: What app are you using? Are you rooted? And can you maybe provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

That's just the new Google Camera app.
You can uninstall the update and use the stock version instead if that bothers you.